# javascript onclick radio clear textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to clear a text box when a radio button above the text box is selected.

I have tried this:

```
 function clearThis(target){
    target = document.getElementById(target);
   target.value = "";
  }

 <input type="radio" name="not_req" id="clear_req" value="" 
        title="Click here to clear the No Auth need flag"><span id="clear" onclick = 'clearThis("claims")' >Clear
```

The box I would like to clear is

```
 <input type="text" size="5" name="auth_for" id="claims" value="{$prior_auth->get_auth_for()}" title="Set the number of times no auth can be used">
```

Took most of this from http://jsfiddle.net/BMrUb/ but I can see that the example is clearing the adjacent text box. I would like to clear a text box not adjacent to the radio button.

Comment: Then what text box you want to clear?

Comment: place your `onclick=""` in the `<input>`, not the `<span>`.

Comment: the text box id="claims" is what I would like to clear.

Comment: Gerald, that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gerald said place your `onclick=""` in the `<input type="radio" ... >`, not in the `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it's the sibling input element that needs its value clearing, not the span, even though you only want it to clear when people click on the span element. So the example code below does this. You're also best off decoupling your javascript from your HTML by using event listeners (and not using the old-fashioned `onclick` attribute).

```
var clearSpanEl = document.getElementById("clear");

clearSpanEl.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var inputEl = e.target.previousElementSibling;
    inputEl.value = "";
}, false);
```

---

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="I can be cleared" />
<span id="clear">Clear results</span>
```

---

I've forked your JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e0yqyp7z/), so you can see it working.